# Hover effects in same div but different dt

Tags: html, css

I apologize in advance for poor English.

I'm creating a website with a lateral menu. All tabs have dash border and text-shadow. ( Image here -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23141053/Captura%20de%20ecr%C3%A3%202015-01-20%2C%20%C3%A0s%2022.52.35.png )

The goal is not have the border neither the shadow where someone hover a tab. But the others tabs must be in the same way. But the problem is, when I hover a tab, all effects disappear. ( Image here -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23141053/Captura%20de%20ecr%C3%A3%202015-01-20%2C%20%C3%A0s%2022.56.20.png )

I know I can create an id to all tabs and use that to control my problem but I just need something more "clean".

Can you help me?
Keep smiling!
Alexandra

```css
.mainRibbon dl {
  margin-top: 220px;
}
.mainRibbon dl,
.mainRibbon dl a {
  font-family: pacifico;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  -moz-text-decoration-line: underline;
  -moz-text-decoration-style: dashed;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}
.mainRibbon dl:hover,
.mainRibbon dl:hover a {
  font-family: pacifico;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.mainRibbon dl p {
  font-family: pacifico;
  color: #6abbfe;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainRibbon">
  <dl>
    <dt>Ementa</dt>
    <p>diária</p>
    <a href="especialidades.html">
      <dt>Especialidades</dt>
      <p>por encomenda</p>
    </a>
    <a href="bebidas.html">
      <dt>Bebidas</dt>
      <p>& Sobremesas</p>
    </a>
    <a href="contactos.html">
      <dt>Contactos</dt>
      <p>horários & encomendas</p>
    </a>
  </dl>
  <p class="picanha">Venha experimentar a nossa Picanha ao fim-de-semana.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: When you change `.mainRibbon dl:hover, .mainRibbon dl:hover a`  to `.mainRibbon dl a:hover` I would guess it is at least partially solved?  But I'm not sure why you use `.mainRibbon dl:hover` at all? What do you try to achieve with this?

Comment: An additional note: Your html is invalid that way. A [`<dl>`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-dl-element) can only contain `<dt>` and  `<dd>` elements. An `<a>` element is invalid there. Normally a browser would _fix_ such an invalid html, to create a valid DOM. For you example this does not happen (at least in Chrome an FF), but I guess this only to not break older sites.

Comment: First com.: .mainRibbon dl:hover is there because the first tab doesn't have an anchor but it needs to have the same reation too.

Answer (score 0):

Apply your css only to the `<a>` element, not the `<dl>`. Something like this:

```
.mainRibbon dl:hover a {
    font-family: pacifico;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much t.niese. Your answear helped me understanding the problem.

Here is the code for future doubts from other people.

```
.mainRibbon dl{
    margin-top:220px;   
}

.mainRibbon dl dt, .mainRibbon dl dt a{
    font-family: pacifico;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    -moz-text-decoration-line: underline;
    -moz-text-decoration-style: dashed;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}

.mainRibbon dl dt:hover, .mainRibbon dl a:hover{
    font-family: pacifico;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow:none;
}

.mainRibbon dl dd{
    font-family: pacifico;
    color: #6abbfe;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

<div class="mainRibbon">
            <dl>
                <dt>Ementa</dt>
                    <dd>diária</dd>
                <dt><a href="especialidades.html">Especialidades</a></dt>
                    <dd>por encomenda</dd>
                <dt><a href="bebidas.html">Bebidas</a></dt>
                    <dd>& Sobremesas</dd>
                <dt><a href="contactos.html">Contactos</a></dt>
                    <dd>horários & encomendas<dd>
            </dl>
            <p class="picanha">Venha experimentar a nossa Picanha ao fim-de-semana.</p>
        </div>
```